# Does IBM MobileFirst capture Analytics if we are connection directly to rest server using WLResourceRequest

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, mobilefirst-server

I am trying to connect to my Development Rest Server using Ibm MobileFirst Apis(WLResourceRequest).And it works fine for me ....

I used it as mentioned in the following link
 [Does Mobilefirst provide a provision to access web services directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160925/does-mobilefirst-provide-a-provision-to-access-web-services-directly/35165098#35165098])

My question is as MobileFirst captures all the analytics for adapters calls like Backend Response Time,Average Request Size etc. Will all these data also gets captured for direct rest server calls.

If not how would I make it capture analytics for rest service calls also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `WLResourceRequest` to connect backends other than the MobileFirst server then you will get some analytics information but not as detailed.

For example if you use the following:

```
var req = new WLResourceRequest('https://www.yourotherbackendservice.com/your/resource/path/', 'GET');
req.send().then(function(e){
    // OK
}, function(e){
    // handle error
});
```

The you will get things like **Roundtrip Time** and **Response Size** but you will NOT get **Backend Response Time** because that is calculated by the MobileFirst Server.